# Not a pagination, a small navigation between the results

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a Diary in my application, it has many posts. Each post has one individual page for itself.

I need a small navigation between them that shows the posts one by one with a "previous" and "next" navigation, but I have no idea about how to do that.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "individual page". Is it a full page content or some verbiage contained in the db?
Generally, you have two approaches you'll need Navigate action method to return the html content (partial) or the entire Page View.  Using parameters on the method, such as navigation=forward|back and page, you can create links to the next and previous page.

Comment: An individual page is one page where I see only one post with its messages from friends and comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
public void NavigateNext(Post current)
{
  var post = (from p in db.Posts
             where p.CreateDate > current.CreateDate
             order by p.CreateDate).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

 //do something

}

public void NavigateBack(Post current)
{
  var post = (from p in db.Posts
             where p.CreateDate < current.CreateDate
             order by p.CreateDate desc).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

 //do something

}
```

Comment: Good hint, I had a good idea based on this post, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Create a method ex. Navigation and just pass in the page number:

```
public Diary Navigation(int page)
{
   Diary diary = (from d in db.Diaries
                 where d.Id = page
                 select d)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
                 // or .Take(1);

   return diary;
}
```

Something similar as it's done in paging.